# Java error - Send is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in Runnable

Tags: java

I am getting the following error when I try to compile my java work.

```
Send.java:16: error: Send is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in Runnable
public class Send implements Runnable {
       ^
1 error
```

My code for Send.java is

```
public class Send implements Runnable {

    private byte[] data = new byte[0];
    private String from = "";
    static DataOutputStream out = null;


    public Send(byte[] data, String from) throws IOException {
        data = data;
        from = from;

        out = Server.os;


        Log.logInfo("Data:" + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data) + "");
        Log.logInfo("From:" + from + "");
        Log.logInfo("OS:" + out + "");




    }

}
```

And the code for defining the os outputstream in the server file is:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    public static DataOutputStream os = null;
    private DataInputStream is = null;

    public Server(String originalHost) throws Exception {
        socket = new Socket(originalHost, 9339);

        Log.logInfo("* Connected to Server");
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        int bytes_read;
        try {

            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
....
```

I need to keep the send.java code for getting the outputstream the same because soon it will also be getting the same variable from another file depending on an if statement.

Does any have an idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the Send class implement the Runnable interface but do not override the run() method like you do in your server class.

Implement the following method inside of your Send class:

```
@Override
public void run() {}
```

Comment: there is no run() in send class though.

Comment: Right, that is the problem. When you implement the Runnable interface in a class you need to implement its methods. The Runnable interface requires you to implement a run method.

Comment: That would be for another question. But, I can see that is because you are not creating an instance of you "Server" class but rather using the static class OutputStream inside the Server class (Server.os) which is defined as null. You need to instantiate and start your Server class as you don't define your OutputStream until the run method (which also you should use your class variable os and not create a new one in the method).

Comment: got it working by saving the socket from server/client and then making the dataoutputstream from it. thanks!